# How to design and determine CR of a respawning horde encounter?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, pathfinder-1e

I wish to design an encounter where players must reach a place or press a kind of switch while waves of enemies attack them. Enemies should continue respawning as players pursue their objective. The question is how to design a well-balanced encounter in terms of respawn rate. Let's say my party is formed of 6 players of level 10. How to calculate the CR of an encounter of this kind?

Comment: It sounds to me like the distance to the switch is significant.  Perhaps base it on the number of enemies that can fit between the players and the switch (and so need to be cut down to reach the switch)?  Any enemies that aren't close enough to stop the players are just flavor.

Comment: All I can hear in the back of my head is "Elf shot the food!"

Comment: You have tags for two systems with significant differences in encounter math. Which are you actually using?

Comment: I think the guidelines for should be the same in terms of challenge, whichever of the two system you use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is actually really tricky, because you want several attributes of this encounter. You want creatures to provide a challenge, but you also don't want the challenge to be too much for them to handle.

Obviously, your characters will want to get to the switch to shut of the monster flow. I'm assuming they know this or will figure it out *really quickly*.

If I wanted the overall encounter to be hard, I would do the following:

1. The number of current enemies between the players and the switch constitute a medium, run-of-the-mill encounter. Enough to make the players concerned, but not a harder than normal challenge.
2. Have the spawner (constructor? summoner?) spawn additional monsters which would make it a hard encounter. Specifically, they spawn enough for a hard encounter over the time it takes your average party member to turn off the spawner / constructor / summoner.

I'm assuming that, when the switch is thrown, the PCs still need to worry about killing the spawned monsters. This is why the total number of monsters need to be enough to make a "hard" encounter. If the switch kills/disables all enemies, then you need to increase the initial difficulty.

There are other things to consider to further improve the encounter. Are your players tactically minded enough to send one person forward to shut it off? Will your players slog through the horde, killing everything as they go? Are there many small minions spawned, and can people in the party handle having multiple attacks hitting them, or must they rely on one or two people to defend all the others? What are the consequences of these? Sadly, with 3.5, only experience and knowledge of your player behavior can really answer these questions.

Comment: I have in mind the PC escape from a undead horde in a necropolis. Enemies would respawn in a Descent way, from the out of the LoS. PCs should reach some safe place. I'll try your way. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

When thinking about this question you should also take into the account the tumble skill. ( If using the 3.5 system ) A character can tumble one half their speed around enemies without provoking attacks of opportunity. If the character has a cleric buff like Elation or is a naturally fast class like a monk they will be able to tumble across a room relatively quickly to press the button just by taking a double-move.

To circumvent this I suggest making the room longer than it is wide. Make more than one spawner, and make the spawner spit out monsters once a round until its trigger is activated. The monsters should be numerous, likely a low CR, and once spawned they would need to be killed normally. Keep this in mind when creating the encounter. If you expect the PCs to reach the lever in 3 rounds and each spawner is spitting out 1 monster per round once a pressure plate is triggered, there will be six monsters.

If you have a wizard you should stress that when/if he attempts to use Mage hand ( if he thinks to do so ) that the lever requires more than 5 pounds of force to move. Telekinesis or Telekinetic force would be an instant puzzle solver in this situation, as they could pull the lever from up to 400ft away. So keep this encounter in the low levels so its actually difficult.

Calculate the CR based on the amount of enemies you expect the spawners to spit out before the portals are closed. If less/more are spawned just change the CR based on the amount of monsters the PCs have to kill.

Comment: You posted some interesting ideas, but you didn't answer the question, which was how to calculate the challenge rating for such an encounter. All you said was they should have "a low CR", but nothing about how much lower compared to the party level.

Comment: Amended question.